# multi threaded program not behaving as expected for signal handling

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

I have written C code to have understanding of how pthreads behave in face of receiving a signal. For this, I have setup a signal handler using sigaction, done fork to create child process, setup number of pthreads from child process, and sent a signal from parent process to child process. I am printing id of thread from signal handler.

I had read that when a process has number of threads, then the signal will be handled by any of the threads and the behaviour is undefined (that is not sure of which thread will handle the signal). But what I have observed in my program is that every time the signal handler is printing id of only one thread and this seems to be id of parent thread. I was expecting that random id of any of the threads will be printed every time the signal is sent, but this is not happening. Can someone please throw some light on this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h> 

pthread_t tid[5];

void* doSomeThing2(void *arg)
{
    int i;
    printf("In thread handler.my pid is %x\n",pthread_self());
    i=5;
    while(i--)
    {
            sleep(1);
    }
    return NULL;
}

static void my_completion_handler( int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context )
{
    int ret;

    printf("In completion handler.my pid is %x\n",pthread_self());

    return;
}

int main()
{
    int ret,err;
    struct sigaction sig_act;
    pid_t mypid;
    int i,j;

    /* Setup the signal handler */
    sigemptyset(&sig_act.sa_mask);
    sig_act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sig_act.sa_sigaction = my_completion_handler;

    /* Map the Signal to the Signal Handler */
    ret = sigaction( SIGTERM, &sig_act, NULL );

    mypid=fork();

    switch(mypid) {
            case -1:
                    printf("fork failed\n");
                    return -1;
            case 0:
                    /* child process */
                    printf("In child process,my pid is %x\n",pthread_self());
                    for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
                            err = pthread_create(&(tid[j]), NULL, &doSomeThing2, NULL);
                            if (err != 0)
                                    printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
                    }

                    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
                    {
                            pthread_join(tid[j], NULL);
                    }
                    exit(0);
            default:
                    /* parent process */
                    printf("Got child pid of %d\n",mypid);
                    i=5;
                    while(i--)
                    {
                            sleep(1);
                            printf("Parent sending signal to child \n");
                            kill(mypid,SIGTERM);
                    }

                    break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I executed this program, I got below results:

```
root@sri-ThinkCentre-M72e:/home/sri/Downloads# ./signal-fork 
Got child pid of 10049
In child process,my pid is b7573700
In thread handler.my pid is b6d71b40
In thread handler.my pid is b6570b40
In thread handler.my pid is b5d6fb40
In thread handler.my pid is b7572b40
In thread handler.my pid is b556eb40
Parent sending signal to child 
In completion handler.my pid is b7573700
Parent sending signal to child 
In completion handler.my pid is b7573700
Parent sending signal to child 
In completion handler.my pid is b7573700
Parent sending signal to child 
In completion handler.my pid is b7573700
Parent sending signal to child 
In completion handler.my pid is b7573700
```

Comment: "Undefined" doesn't mean "random".

Comment: So is it that the signal will be handled always in the context of the parent thread?

Comment: No, where the signal will be handled is *undefined*.